# Multiple merchant ids with different bank accounts

Tags: ios, itunes, applepay

is it possible to have two different apps with each having its own merchant id?
I mean, how will this work?

I want if a user makes purchase on one app, the money will be redirected to a specific bank account.
And for the other app the money should be redirected to another bank account.
Is this possisble?

Comment: Are you talking about in-app purchases or purchases made through a payment gateway like Stripe, for physical good or real-world services?

Comment: @Pauw11, I think he's talking about applePay